# Combine two pandas DataFrames with one unique column each and keep the row index (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I tried to combine two dataframes into one. 
Each dataframe has one unique column name. 
The row indices may overlap between both dataframes, but there are also unique ones.

Here is an example:

```
df1  = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df2  = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnB': [5, 6, 7, 8]}, index=['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'])
```

I expect as a result the following:

```
 ColumnA   ColumnB
a 1        5
b 2        6
c 3        NaN
d 4        NaN
e NaN      7
f NaN      8
```

I tried the following:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

I also tried this:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Both with the results, that unique rows are gone.

Can anyone help me here?
Thanks.

Comment: great first question, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried *merge* and *concat*, but there is yet another method.

Run:

```
df1.join(df2, how='outer')
```

Comment: Thanks. It was just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC `combine_first` or `join`

```
df1.combine_first(df2)

   ColumnA  ColumnB
a      1.0      5.0
b      2.0      6.0
c      3.0      NaN
d      4.0      NaN
e      NaN      7.0
f      NaN      8.0
```

or

```
df1.join(df2,how='outer')

   ColumnA  ColumnB
a      1.0      5.0
b      2.0      6.0
c      3.0      NaN
d      4.0      NaN
e      NaN      7.0
f      NaN      8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

[`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) has a parameter `how` using `'outer'` yields desired results.

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
   ColumnA  ColumnB
a      1.0      5.0
b      2.0      6.0
c      3.0      NaN
d      4.0      NaN
e      NaN      7.0
f      NaN      8.0
```